# Batch file continues to run command after Task Scheduler stops it

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, robocopy, task-scheduler

I have a scheduled task running at `00:00` that opens a `.bat` file containing a `robocopy` command, with the task set to stop after 4 minutes, and to force stop if not ending when requested.

It seems the Task Scheduler stop command is ignored until the `robocopy` command finishes, which seems to me to defeat the point - is there a way around this?

- The message I would expect is in the history at `00:04`, however the output file of `robocopy` continues running for a further 4 minutes, only stopping at `00:08`:

  > Task Scheduler terminated `{uuid}`  instance of the `Taskname` task due to exceeding the time allocated for execution, as configured in the task definition.  
  > User Action: Increase the configured task timeout or investigate external reasons for the delay.
- There are other commands in the `.bat` file, but the `robocopy` step is the one running at the time the scheduler tried to stop the task, with the command after it not running:

  ```powershell
   MkDir "C:\Destination\Folder"
     RoboCopy "C:\Source\Folder" "C:\Destination\Folder" /MOV /IS /S /R:0 /LOG:"C:\output.txt"
     RmDir "C:\Destination\Folder" /s /q
  ```

Comment: I believe this is normal behavior, as the task and script are two separate entities - while the task starts the script, the script isn't the task, so it should run to completion independent of the task itself _(at least this has been my experience with starting a `RoboCopy` script in Task Scheduler)_. Microsoft Docs for [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) would need to be referenced _(IIRC, the task itself garnishes script completion or errors from an event within Event Viewer, although I could be misremembering)_

Comment: @JW0914 thank you for the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JW0914 says right:

> I believe this is normal behavior, as the task and script are two separate entities - while the task starts the script, the script isn't the task, so it should run to completion independent of the task itself *(at least this has been my experience with starting a `RoboCopy` script in Task Scheduler)*. Microsoft Docs for Task Scheduler would need to be referenced *(IIRC, the task itself garnishes script completion or errors from an event within Event Viewer, although I could be misremembering)*

Here we can work around this behaviour, since this is a plain `robocopy` command with no batch syntax at all, by using *Create basic task* without creating the batch file:

1. Open Task scheduler → Create → Create basic task
2. Name task and set description
3. Set trigger
4. Choose time
5. Action → Run a program:

   - Program/Script: `C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe`
   - Arguments:

     ```
     "C:\Source\Folder" "C:\Destination\Folder" /MOV /IS /S /R:0 /log:"C:\output.txt"
     ```
6. Finish

Comment: Ah, so the scheduler cannot cancel the copy, only the .bat. Unfortunately there is other commands in the file, but only because whoever wrote it wanted to delete the contents of source folder. I will append the full file to the question

Comment: @RichardHarris how about creating multiple tasks??

Comment: This answers my question, though my problem was that the task was occasionally overrunning into another one and it didn't matter if it was done. I've put the .bat files into one task now and they seem to run in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

need some help to write an simple script.

need to trigger an proccess when cpu get below 12% and running for 5 min kill the process. any ideas

$processor = (Get-Process).CPU

$processes_to_kill = get-process Omnis* |

```
Where-Object {$_.$process.cpu -le 12 -and {($_.process.starttime).TotalSeconds -gt 300} }
```

if ($processes_to_kill -ne $null)

{

```
$processes_to_kill | ForEach-Object { $_.Kill() }
```

}